# How do I easily get a key from a value in a Hashmap in Java

Tags: java

I can't seem to find any easy way of getting a key from a value in a HashMap in java.  What I find I either do not understand or does not explain the actual process of getting the key from the value but it does explain the tool to use.

Comment: There isn't one.  HashMaps are designed to get values from keys, not the other way around.  There are slow O(n) hacky ways, though.

Comment: There could be many keys referencing the same value.

Comment: You can use iterator to get all keys and values...!

Comment: also note that the values can be duplicated. (different keys can have same values)

Answer (score 4):

Maps are designed to have quick key→value lookups, but not vice versa.

1. If you need a value given a key, one simple solution is to create a second parallel map that has the reverse mapping. You'd have two maps, one from A to B and another from B to A.
2. Or, using Google's [Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki), you could use a [`BiMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html), which supports lookups in both directions.

If you really want to do this with a regular map, you'll have to iterate through all of the entries. There could be multiple keys with the same value, so you'll want to account for that.

Let's say you have a map from `Key`s to `Value`s.

```
Map<Key, Value> map = ...;
```

Using [Java 8 streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) you could write:

```
Key key = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == value)
    .map(entry -> entry.getKey())
    .findAny()
    .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
```

That would work well if you know there's always one and only one matching value. If there could be multiple, you could build a collection of keys.

```
Set<Key> keys = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == value)
    .map(entry -> entry.getKey())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```